# Use data driven pages to display certain data in each page

Tags: arcmap, data-driven-pages, layouts

In ArcMap, is it possible to use data driven pages to display certain data based on an attribute. I want the extent to remain unchanged across pages, and just have certain data be symbolized differently so it stands out.

I would like to have my first page highlight points where DEPTH is 0-5, 2nd page 5-10, etc...

I know how to use data driven pages to move the extent based on a layer, but this is different.

Comment: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/page-layouts/using-page-definition-queries.htm

Comment: Thank you @jbalk I did not know about the page definition query option through data driven pages.